# Is Visual Studio 2013 Professional not available through WebsiteSpark?

Tags: websitespark

I am aware that WebsiteSpark has been cancelled (along with Technet), but I know the accounts are still active until March.

I went to grab VS 2013 Professional only to find the following message:

> This product is not available at your subscription level. Learn More

Will WebsiteSpark users be getting Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: There should be 2 licenses available like there were with past versions of VS Pro. On a side note, did you have trouble renewing your account? I have not been able to get past the screen to renew for almost one month now (it just doesn't seem to work).

Comment: Yeah I can't get past that screen either, but I can go straight to the MSDN downloads when I sign in.

Comment: Yes, I have to go through MSDN, as well.  Clicking on the 'Upgrade Membership' button on WebSiteSpark does nothing.  Wonder if this is intentional?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to buy a MSDN subscription, buy you can try the Release candidate before it is released officially.

Go to your product keys page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/keys/

If a key is listed for VS 2013 then you should be able to try it out.

You can download it from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/2013-editions#d-professional

Then, after installing, instead of signing into your account, you can register the product with the static key.

Here is what MS says:

"The product key is not embedded with Visual Studio 2013. When you launch the product, you can simply sign in with the Microsoft account associated with your MSDN subscription and your IDE will automatically activate. An added benefit of signing in to Visual Studio is that your IDE settings will sync across devices, and you can connect to online developer services. ***If you’d rather enter a product key, then simply bypass signing in and enter the product key found here by selecting Register Product under the Help menu.***"

Comment: Where do you see the "If you’d rather enter a product key, then simply bypass signing in and enter the product key found here by selecting Register Product under the Help menu"?? Id doesn't say it for me, and no key is shown!?

Comment: Ok, the relevant part is "If you don’t have an MSDN subscription" :] Thanks!